# Date conversion from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table which currently has a varchar(10) Date Column in DD/MM/YYYY format (it is imported automatically from an Excel File daily, I have no control over the Excel File).

I need this to display as the Date Format YYYY/MM/DD (also in ASC order)

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), DOR, 111) as
 'DateOfReg' FROM Fleet06Feb24
 order by 'DateOfReg' ASC
```

Comment: Why does the table not store a date in a column of `date` datatype, perhaps fix that?

Comment: Care to tell us what the problem is with your query - preferably with examples.

Comment: To convert your string "date" into actual date is of course `select convert(date, COLNAME, 103)` -- see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Don't use string literals for aliases. Some syntaxes are deprecated and `order by 'DateOfReg' ASC` does *literally* nothing; if you are sorting your data by a **literal string** the  every row has the same ordinal position, so the ordering will be completely arbitrary.

Comment: As for the problem, fix your design; the format is a presentation layer problem. Store the data as what it is, a *`date`*.

Answer (score 0):

it must be something like that:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(date, DOR, 103), 23) AS DateOfReg
FROM Fleet06Feb24
ORDER BY DateOfReg ASC;
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: Varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)